# Divergence of a velocity field and consequences for the $w$ direction that is not measured

Tags: vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

**Background information**: In this assignment we will use what we have learned in the course to analyze
a data set measured in the Hydrodynamic Laboratory at the Mathematical Institute.
The experiment was done in a tube, the tube has a circular cross section
radius 5 cm. The measurements were made with "Particle Imaging Velocimetry"
(PIV). This enables us to measure the velocity field. Note tah we 
Only measures the speed components $u$ in the $x$-direction and $v$ in the $y$-direction. The
The full velocity field is $\vec{v}=u\vec{i}+v\vec{j}+w\vec{k}$, but we do not measure it
speed component in the $z$-direction

**Problem:** We can accurately assume that both the gas and the liquid are
incompressible because the flow is significantly slower than the sound speed
in air and in water.
*Explain the consequences of this for the divergence of $v$ and what we are in
In that case, say the speed component $w$ that we have not measured

**Approach:** Since the water and gas are incompressible, it means that the water and the gas do not change
densist by compression. Since the water and gas do not change the densities, so is the density
the same. Since the density is constant, we can follow from the continuity equation that the (Current field/Stream field?) is
divergence free. We can say that if the flow rate in the water and in the gas is less than $330$
m / s in air, and $1500$ m / s in water, so we can say that it is divergence free. Since the flow in our
Example is slower than the sound speed in water and in air, we can say that we have divergence-free.
Since the velocity field is divergence-free, then $w$ is a constant.

Is this correct? Or do I need to explain further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems correct to me.
To be especially precise, maybe you could say that the flow speed is *much* less than the speed of sound, so the model is justified.